# Ruby / Rails: determine how deeply nested an object is

Tags: ruby, activerecord, model, nested, depth

I think this is a general ruby question, though in my case the objects involved are ActiveRecord models.

If I have a model that can be nested inside of another model, how can I determine how deeply nested the model is?

IE:

```
Model Root (Level 0)
- Model Level 1
- - Model Level 2
- - Model Level 2
- - Model Level 2
- - - Model Level 3
- - - Model Level 3
- Model Level 1
- Model Level 1
```

In let's say `foo` is a model nested three levels deep (as shown above). If I call `foo.parent.parent.parent` I would get the root model.

How could I define a method like: `foo.depth` that would return how many levels there are between foo and its root?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
def depth
  parent.nil? ? 0 : 1+parent.depth
end
```

Comment: Wow! Simple, elegant, very ruby. This works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [recursive method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29). Something like:

```
class Sample

  attr_accessor :parent

  def depth

    # Base case.
    return 0 if parent.nil?

    # Recursive case.
    return parent.depth + 1

  end

end
```

This is assuming that your parent class will always respond to 'depth'. If not, you need to do some checks on `respond_to?`.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the answer, this is a helpful elaboration. This is the same as Wizard of Ogz answer, but I picked his because I like the ternary operator and bc you have 4000 more reputation than he does :) Thanks though!!

Comment: Also thanks for the tip on `respond_to?`. In my case all the objects will respond to depth, but that's a very good head's up!